# Machine learning after canny edge detection for detecting quadrilateral shapes?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, edge-detection

Basically, I would be doing a document extraction using Canny and hough. After Canny edge detection, I am getting a lot of edges which are detected from the document.

**Results after Canny edge detector:**

[image: Results after Canny edge detector.]

but I need only the edges of the document which is not just a rectangle. I searched for object localization using machine learning but they all take input in form of rectangular bounding box while I need a quadrilateral one. Is there any machine learning which I can train and extract the edges of the document?

**Expected Output after Machine learning edge detection:**

[image: Expected Output after Machine learning edge detection]

Comment: You have a good start on your question - but you'll want to add:  what specifically did you try (show the code!) And also some more info on what you think might be causing the gap with the expected behavior

Comment: Till now, I have made masks of every image with the desired edge and these masks are black & white images with edges being the white. On what machine learning models can I train these images along with their masks?

Answer (score 0):

Apply strong horizontal-only blur before edge detection, and repeat vertically.

Comment: I'm assuming your approach means to apply the two steps in parallel to the original image and then combine them ? That would work if the horzontal and vertical edge detection were disjoint. Is it your experience that they can be generated and  combined cleanly?